# Extend Python class's init method

Tags: python, oop

I have a `BaseClass` and an `AbstractClass` that inherits from the `BaseClass`. This is the structure I have in place

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, initialize=True):
        self.name = 'base_class'
        self.start = 0
        if initialize:
            self.start = 100

class AbstractClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'asbtract_class'
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__()
```

I want to pass the abstract class an `initialize` parameter that gets transferred to the base class and if `True` sets the object's `start` value to `100`.

I tried using the `super(BaseClass, self).__init__()` but the abstract class gets no `start` attribute. I get an error when I try to access it.

How can I pass a value the `initialize` argument to the  `AbstractClass` and  use the `BaseClass`'s `__init__` method to set the `start` attribute on the `AbstractClass`.

The code I used

```
best = BaseClass()
abs = AbstractClass()
abs.start # AttributeError: 'AbstractClass' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Comment: If you are using Python3, you can simplify it to `super().__init__()`

Comment: @Sraw It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke the constructor of the super class you should use the class name of the sub class and not the super class, i.e.:

```
class AbstractClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AbstractClass, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'abstract_class'
```

Note also that I changed the order of invoking the constructor of the super class and setting the `name` attribute. If you set it before calling the super, the attribute would be overridden by the constructor of the super class, which is most likely not what you intended

And as @Sraw pointed out, for python 3 the notation of calling the super no longer requires the referencing of the class name and can be simplified to

```
class AbstractClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can access the `start` param now. But I also need to be able to pass the `initialize` argument from the `AbstractClass `. I mean something like this: `abs = AbstractClass(initialize=False)`. Is there a way of doing that? Currently, this throws an error.

Comment: Just add the param to `AbstractClass.__init__` and pass it when doing the `super().__init__()` call. No magic involved here, it's just plain ordinary boring function calls...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay, got it working now. Thanks